# How can I find the roots of the maximizer of a function?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I define $x(b) = \arg \max (-x^2/2+bx)$.
I'd like to find the values of $b$ such that $x(b) = 0$. I tried running the code

```
x[b_] := x /. FindMaximum[-x^2/2 + b x, x][[2]]
FindRoot[x[b] == 0, {b, 0}]
```

but I get an error, even though the function `x` seems to work. I know this is a somewhat trivial example (since $x(b) = b$), but in the application I have in mind the maximizer may not have a closed form expression.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `_?NumericQ`: `x[b_?NumericQ] := x /. FindMaximum[-x^2/2 + b x, x][[2]];`

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/193)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NMaximize` instead of `FindMaximum`, with `_?NumericQ` as pointed out by [Michael E2 in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128475/how-can-i-find-the-roots-of-the-maximizer-of-a-function#comment347502_128475) (I changed the name of the function from `x[b]` to `max[b]` because I simply dislike naming different things with the same symbol):

```
max[b_?NumericQ] := x /. NMaximize[-x^2/2 + b x, x][[2]]

max[1]
```

> 1

```
Plot[max[b], {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[max[b] == 0, {b, 0}]
```

> {b -> 0.}

---

With a different example:

```
max[b_?NumericQ] := x /. NMaximize[Sin[b x] + Cos[x] - x^2 + (b - 1)/b x, x][[2]];

max[0.5]
```

> -0.167512

```
Plot[max[b], {b, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[max[b] == 0, {b, 0.5}]
```

> {b -> 0.618034}

Comment: What determines whether Maximize, NMaximize, or FindMaximum work in this context?